# Integrating oracle 11g with Grails and Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, gradle, oracle11g

I have created a simple grails 3 application. I am trying to connect it to an Oracle database in the datasource configuration.

When I run

```
SELECT * FROM V$VERSION
```

in sql developer, the following data is returned back about my database.

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
```

my application.yml file looks like this:

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        driverClassName: 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
        username: 'superCool'
        password: 'password'
        url: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:coolio'
        dbCreate: ''
```

my build.gradle file contains these lines for hibernate and oracle dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    (...)
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.5"
    (...)
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile("com.oracle:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2")
}
```

My service file looks as follows:

```
class DatabaseService {

DataSource dataSource

public void testMyDb(User user) {
    try {
        registerUser(new Sql(dataSource), user)
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("unable to register the user", e)
        throw e
    }
}

public void registerUser(Sql sql, User user) {
        sql.call("{call isertUser(?)}", [user.name])
}
```

If I remove the

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.5"
```

from the build.gradle, I can run my integration tests and the database is successfully reached. If I keep it there, I get the following error:

```
ERROR DatabaseService - unable to register the user
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:2254) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
```

UPDATE 1:

I updated my build.gradle file to reference

```
compile("com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.2")
```

as opposed to

```
compile("com.oracle:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2")
```

and the generated error now refers to the setter:

```
ERROR DatabaseService - unable to register the user
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.setAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:2254) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
```

UPDATE 2:

I caught the SQLException and got the sql error code from it. The code returned back: 08003. According to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15817_01/appdev.111/b31228/appd.htm ,

```
08003 - connection does not exist
```

So at this point, I set the pooled flag to false in the datasource, and everything worked just fine. So the problem here is narrowed down to that. The plugin is not reacting well to the pooled properties.

I have issued the following sql commands to figure out the size of my pool:

```
SELECT name, value  FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'sessions';
```

that returns back 1524.

I have also issued the sql command to see the current allocated amount:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v$session;
```

which returns back 58.

I suppose the question now is, what is causing the pooled property to go crazy.

Comment: Did you try another hibernate version? For example newer: `compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.0.RC1"`? Or even downgrade to latest Hibernate3: `runtime "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:3.6.10.19"`?

Comment: @majkelo just tried your reccomendation, and it seems to not solve anything. same error :/

Comment: Did you `grails clean` and `grails compile --non-interactive --refresh-dependencies` before restarting and checking each of dependiencies?

Comment: Moreover isn't there a typo in `registerUser(Sql sql, User user)` function: `call isertUser` -> `call insertUser`

Comment: i did a regular clean and compile initially. I performed the one you state, and it caused around 30 errors, with the most dominant being a failure to start the embedded app server when using the downgraded version.

Comment: @majkelo the function calls are correct. As mentioned before, its only the hibernate plugin in the build that causes the exception to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to disable my pooling. I cannot tell if its a bug, r why it fails, but it does. Thankfully for me, I used jndi lookup for my dataSources, so replacing that made the spark.

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: false
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        driverClassName: 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
        username: 'superCool'
        password: 'password'
        url: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:coolio'
        dbCreate: ''
```